# R package version number not updated with update.package()

Tags: r

I'm using R package “sendmailR" version 1.1-1 on Linux x86_64 server and would like to update to version 1.1-2. I used `update.packages("sendmailR")` command. However, after the update is finished, I checked the version number `packageVersion("sendmailR")` and it is still refer to 1.1-1. I checked all the libraries and the time stamp on the folder is not updated.

Do you have any idea why it’s not updating ? Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Check `repos` arg in `update.packages` also check compiled binaries on the particular repo.

Comment: After you updated, did you do `library("sendmailR")`?  If not the old version was still 'active'.

Comment: I have tried both suggestions. Its still reference to older version.

Comment: Delete old version and install it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer to my own question.
R utility function `update.packages()` doesn't take package name as an argument and doesn't update packages individually. Instead it take library location as an argument. To update a package use `update.packages(/<library-location>, ask = TRUE)` if the package has new version on CRAN it will give you an option to update. If you would like to update type `y` and vise versa.